# How do I obtain the properties of an existing Transit Gateway with the CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am deploying my app into an account that has a Transit Gateway shared from another AWS account via Resource Access Manager.

The Transit Gateway isn't created by the CDK. It doesn't exist in a different stack or an app.

I want to create a Transit Gateway VPC Attachment to that Transit Gateway.

To create the Transit Gateway VPC Attachment object I need to supply a Transit Gateway ID. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnTransitGatewayVpcAttachment.html#class-cfntransitgatewayvpcattachment-construct

I cannot find a way with the CDK to obtain the Transit Gateway ID from an existing Transit Gateway.  What method would I use to obtain the Transit Gateway ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your SDK to look it up.

During the deploy of a stack, use your languages SDK (such as boto3 for python) to access the AWS API commands to look up the information and retrieve it. I do this regularly with Layers that are identical across multiple stacks, but you need the version number to import a layer (i don't want to create multiple versions of the same layer) - I use boto3 to get the most recent version of the layer and the from_attributes command to import it into the stack.

You can do something similar with whatever SDK implementation for your chosen languages replicates this CLI command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-transit-gateways.html

Comment: As of today, this looks like the best solution.  Without a lookup function I'll have to resort to using the AWS SDK to find the Transit Gateway ID.  I've created a Feature Request on the AWS CDK Github project for a lookup method.  https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16873

Comment: Given that the CDK is in the same languages as the SDK, this methodology is kind of expected to be used. The fact that the Transit Gateway is a Cfn Function means that it has not been fully put into CDK - the cfn functions are temporary wrappers around a very base conversion to cloudformation (hence cfn) templates. They do not have most of the hooks that other CDK Constructs have.

So its possible it will have it when they get to moving it into a proper construct.

In any case, infrastructure as code means using the SDK is perfectly acceptable for many situations, and in fact, encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the method to "lookup" the existing Transit Gateway in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnTransitGateway.html

I assume you could either

- Export the Transit Gateway ID as a CloudFormation output in the stack where it is created?
- Lookup the Transit Gateway ID yourself and inject it into CDK source code?

I ended up with 2nd option in one of the projects and did not face any issues later.

Comment: In this case, the Transit Gateway isn't created by the CDK at all.  It doesn't exist in a different stack or an app. I can't export it as CloudFormation output, nor can I store the value in SSM Parameter Store.